# Is it possible to include a search command in a macro?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to create a macro that enters visual mode, selects some text in a particular way, then does a search of that highlighted text using another key mapping I have defined as `vnoremap // y/<C-R>"<CR>`.  However, when I enter the first `/` I observe that it stops recording my macro :(

To simplify, forget about the key mapping... What I want to do is create a macro that visually highlights some text and then does a forward search for that highlighted text.

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question in title: it is possible to include search cmd in a macro.  You just record it by pressing `/foobar<cr>`... **macro** here I meant is done by `q`. `:h q` to see details.

You can test it with simple examples.

Your question is not clear, `vnoremap` creates a key-mapping, not macro. It is also possible in a macro to use the key-mapping you created.

It would be better just convert your requirement into a small example, what you have, and what do you want to get.

Comment: Thanks @Kent.  You're correct.  I guess I was just assuming that the macro recording was stopping when I type the `/` because it hides the "recording" text.